# Check if the value of array 1 is present in the key of array 2 - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have two array:

```
$arr1 = Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Ball
    [2] => whale
    [3] => Dog
    [4] => cat
)
```

and

```
$arr2 = Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [Red apple] => 27
            [tball] => 28
            [cat] => 29
            [Dog] => 30
            [blue ball] => 31
        )
    ]
)
```

Here, I want to check if the value of 1st array matches `('% like %')` to any key of second array. I would like to explain it with respect to this example.

Here, you can see 1st value of `$arr1` is `Apple`, now you can see `Red apple` on arr2. This means this should be considered as match. However, `Ball` should not be matched with `tball` instead `Ball` should match to `blue ball`.

If it does find the match then I want the value to be stored in `$result` array, if there is no matched value the particular index of `$result` array must be empty. In this case I want the exact result as:

```
$result= Array
(
    [0] => 27
    [1] => 31
    [2] => 
    [3] => 30
    [4] => 29
)
```

[sandboxphp](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b380b1d0d63a0b4b25fe2b2715caa3432af0c6d6)

Comment: Can't you at least give us arrays that we can use? Var_export or json_encode?

Comment: @Andreas I have provided two array on the above sandbox link. Could you please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your link the real arrays look much larger and I assume a two way match can be possible.
Because of that I made a slight difference to the output the code to group on category.
I'm not sure what to do if there is a match of two, what number should be retrieved?
I also use preg_grep which uses regex on arrays instead of looping the array.
And preg_quote to make sure regex characters does not interfere with the regex.

```
$arr1 = Array('Apple', 'Ball', 'whale', 'Dog', 'cat');
$arr2 = Array('Red apple' => 27, 'tball' => 28, 'cat' => 29, 'Dog' => 30, 'blue ball' => 31, 'dog food' => 25, 'green apple' => 111);
$keys = array_keys($arr2);

foreach($arr1 as $find){
    $matches = preg_grep("/\b" . preg_quote($find) . "/i", $keys);
    foreach($matches as $key => $word){
        $result[$find][] = $arr2[$word];
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output of this:

```
array(4) {
  ["Apple"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(27)
    [1]=>
    int(111)
  }
  ["Ball"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(31)
  }
  ["Dog"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(30)
    [1]=>
    int(25)
  }
  ["cat"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(29)
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/es2Gt

Comment: It totally make sense, however, with real data it is showing some error like Warning: preg_grep(): Unknown modifier '2'  on line 175. Do you have any idea on what might be causing this issue? https://3v4l.org/TYZk3

Comment: @AayushDahal Ha! Learned something new today. `/` is not a character preg_quote handles. But a simple str_replace fixed that. But your arrays do not match anywhere. See here https://3v4l.org/YVpbb

Comment: You can do the matching the other way around so that arr2 is used to match against arr1 and then use the value from arr2. That probably made no sense but just look at the output here: https://3v4l.org/n881a

Comment: Ok, I got it it was because of forward slash. As preg_quote don't escape it and it was the expression that begin and end with. So, I have replaced the forward slash with ` sign it works fine.

Comment: It's no problems using forward slash, just that it needs to be escaped in the string before inserted in regex patterns. Which is what you can do with a str_replace as I did in the code example

Answer (score 1):

hello just try regular exp and try this

```
   $arr1 = Array('Apple', 'Ball', 'whale', 'Dog', 'cat');
    $arr2=Array('Red apple' => 27, 'tball' => 28, 'cat' => 29, 'Dog' => 30, 'blue ball' => 31);
    $array=array();
    foreach ($arr1 as $arr) {
        $flag=false;
        foreach ($arr2 as $a=>$ar) {
            $search = '\b( ?'.$arr.')';
            if(preg_match("/{$search}/i", $a)) {
                array_push($array,$ar);
                $flag=true;
            }
        }
        if (!$flag) {
            array_push($array,'');
        }
    }
    var_dump($array); die;
```

Comment: `$search = '\b( ?'.$arr.')';` what if `$arr` is `one/two`? Use preg_quote

Comment: i can't understand u mean in "what if $arr is one/two"

Comment: @MustafaGoda May be he is referring what if there is `/` (slash) in the word. Anyway could you look at the actual data as it showing warning something like `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '2'`  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4af5f71493f09073c8235fc73ced79719b8d1b2a

Comment: Correct Aayush. Because he is not escaping characters in the strings the regex not always work.